# setInterval printing multiple times

Tags: javascript

I wrote a piece of code involving an `if..else` statement inside a `for-loop`, my goal was to execute the content of the `else` part after 1 second of each iteration. E.g. I am printing  10 to 1. First, 10 will be printed after 1s 9 will be printed and after another 1s 8 will be printed and so on until it's 0. So my approach was

> That `pgn` is important.

```
(function () {
var i, pgn = 0;
for (i = 1; pgn < 10; i++) {
    if (i === 1) {
        console.log(10);
        pgn++;
    }

    else {
        (function countdown() {
            var count1 = 9;
            var myTimer = setInterval(function () {
                console.log(count1);
                count1 -= 1;
                if (count1 <= 0) {
                    clearInterval(myTimer);
                }
            }, 1000);
         })()
        pgn += 1;
      }
}
})()
```

And it gave me a result like this,

```
10
9
9
9
9
and then after several 9s, 8 8 8.. and so on until 0.
```

And then by curiosity, I replaced `pgn += 1;` to `pgn+=10` and the code works exactly as I wanted. It prints 10 and then after a second 9 and so on. Can someone please explain how does it happen?

Comment: The `setInterval` call looks correct. The only problem is that you're calling it nine times instead of just once.

Comment: @LambdaFairy, can you please tell me where did I call it 9 times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setInterval` will call function repeatedly after a given number of milliseconds has been elapsed. When you are incrementing your loop by `1` you are creating multiple timers not a single one and hence as soon as all timers expire, they will log value in the console but when you increase step by `10`, your loop will run only once and will have a single timer.

All you need is:

```
var count1 = 10;
var myTimer =  setInterval(function () {
  console.log(count1);
  count1 -= 1;
  if (count1 <= 0) {
    clearInterval(myTimer);
  }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Yeah that's it. I get it now. Thank you a lot. Please give me an upvote